# Make list items of certain width

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/

I am trying to get rid of the additional space after each `li` item, to make the blocks the same size as their content. I tried to display them as inline, but that removes the bullets.

HTML

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>cherry</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 50%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
li {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I was making the `li` as inline, instead of the `ul`. Why does it behave like that, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in my comment you have to make `ul` `display: inline-block;` like this:

```
ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/4/)

Comment: Can you also explain why does it behave like that, please?

Comment: The browser displays the bullets because the style property "display" is initially set to "list-item". Changing the display property to "inline" cancels all the special styles that list items get.

Comment: You can have same effect if you use `float:left` in your ul list. Look this example http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/14/

Answer (score 1):

try this code   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/11/)

```
div{
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 50%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
     border:1px solid black;
    list-style:inside;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
ul{
           display: inline-block;
    }
```

**Inline-Block**

Basically, it’s a way to make elements inline, but preserving their block capabilities such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings etc.

[More Info Regarding Inline-block](http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/9/)